# Why do I get an error "__init__() missing 1 required positional argument " when my code runs proper?

Tags: python-3.6

The error is only apparent in a competitive code website - "leetcode" when I submit my solution, but it isn't prevalent when I run the code in the online text-editor or on my local machine.

```
class Solution:
def __init__(self, x):
    """
    :type x: str
    :rtype: bool
    """
    self.x = x


def convert_list(self):
    # my_list = list(self.x)
    self.my_list = list(self.x)
    return self.my_list

def store_list(self):
    my_list = list(self.x)
    list_length = len(my_list)
    new_new_list = []

    for i in range(0,list_length):
        new_list = my_list.pop()
        new_new_list.append(new_list)

    return new_new_list

def isPalindrome(self):
    if self.convert_list() == self.store_list():
        return 'true'.lower()
    else:
        return 'false'.lower()


X = Solution(input())
# print(X.store_list())
# print(X.convert_list())
print(X.isPalindrome())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some indentation and is working fine

```
class Solution:
  def __init__(self, x):
    """
    :type x: str
    :rtype: bool
    """
    self.x = x


  def convert_list(self):
    # my_list = list(self.x)
    self.my_list = list(self.x)
    return self.my_list

  def store_list(self):
    my_list = list(self.x)
    list_length = len(my_list)
    new_new_list = []

    for i in range(0,list_length):
        new_list = my_list.pop()
        new_new_list.append(new_list)

    return new_new_list

  def isPalindrome(self):
    if self.convert_list() == self.store_list():
        return 'true'.lower()
    else:
        return 'false'.lower()


X = Solution(input())
# print(X.store_list())
# print(X.convert_list())
print(X.isPalindrome())
```

[image]

Comment: I have not run it elesewhere , the result is from leetcode itself,  i have attached the screenshot as well

Comment: Sorry I mentioned in the question that the error is only prevalent when I try to submit the solution. (not in the playground or when I "run code" for testing it)

Comment: Ok , then its the issue with leetcode , not your code :)